# How to add python system tray to JavaFX program

Tags: python, java, javafx, system-tray

I'm currently writing a JavaFX application and there is no way to have a solid multi-platform system tray (compatibility issues).

I was wondering if I could create the system tray using Python or any other language and add it to my app. How should I integrate the python code to rest of the Java code ? Would there be a way for the system tray to communicate with the main application ?
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by system tray?  Please show an example. Different platforms have different definitions,

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that, here is an example: https://i.imgur.com/ywaxAPo.png

Comment: `awt` supports tray icon, so there's no problem your app also supports tray icon. the only subtlety is to use `Platform::setImplicitExit()` to prevent the platform from stopping the UI thread of your application.

Comment: Not all platforms support the awt trayIcon though, I'm currently on Arch Linux and the tray icon looks really bad, furthermore when I go on Ubuntu, it's does not work at all.

Comment: distribution is irrelevant. KDE and Gnome have no problems. The quality of support depends on the version of the java platform (the version of GTK it uses). If you're using an environment that doesn't support the tray icon, just minimize it instead of stopping it.

Comment: Yes it seems like I'll have to do that, thanks for the answers

Answer (score 1):

You do not say exactly what you need but I would stick to Java and not try to use something from a different language environment.

This library may be what you are looking for: https://github.com/dustinkredmond/FXTrayIcon

Comment: I've already tried using it, and although compatibility on Windows and macOS is good, Linux is not fully supported, either the visual effects and appearance of the icon are wrong, or it straight up crashes on startup.